# combining results from several async/await calls

Tags: node.js, async-await

I want to return the consolidated results from calling many `async/await` functions. Consider my (wrong)  pseudocode below

```
const getRemoteData = async function(uri) {
    // get result from remote server via XMLHttpRequest
    return result;
}

const finalResult {};
const result1 = getRemoteData('http://…');
result1.forEach(async record => {
    // each record has a key for another URI
    const result2 = await getRemoteData(record["uri"]);

    // result2 has a key for yet another URI
    const result3 = await getRemoteData(result2["uri"]);
    finalResult[ result2["uri"] ] = result3;
})

console.log(finalResult);
```

Of course, since `console.log(finalResult)` is called *before* all the interim calls in the `forEach`loop have completed, `finalResult` is empty. How do I return `finalResult` *after* all the entries in `result1` have been processed? I am using the latest version of `nodejs` and, if possible, would rather not use any other `Promise` library. From what I understand, the new `async/await` capabilities should enable me to accomplish what I want.

Comment: I understand that it's pseudo-code but your `getRemoteData()` is just going to Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.map` instead of `.forEach` in order to `.map` each item in `result1` to a `Promise` that resolves once the associated `result3` has been assigned to `finalResult`. Then, use `Promise.all` on that array, which will resolve once all of its Promises have resolved, after which `finalResult` will be populated with everything you need:

```
const getRemoteData = function(uri) {
  // pretty sure you didn't mean to recursively call getRemoteData:
  return someApiCall(uri);
}
const result1 = await getRemoteData('http://…');
const finalResult = {};
await Promise.all(result1.map(async (record) => {
  const result2 = await getRemoteData(record.uri);
  const result3 = await getRemoteData(result2.uri);
  finalResult[result2.uri] = result3;
}));
console.log(finalResult);
```

(note that instead of an `async` function that `await`'s something and returns it immediately, you may as well just `return` the `Promise` directly instead - also, dot notation is usually preferable to bracket notation, bracket notation is when you need to use a variable property name)

Comment: bravo! Thanks for guiding me to the right solution. One question: where is the documentation that would have helped me figure out on my own that I needed to use `map` and not `forEach`?

Comment: `forEach` runs *synchronously* (as do all Javascript functions in the same block without `await` on that line), so I would have googled something like `await foreach`, which could take you to [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)