# combining results from several async/await calls (again)

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Note to would-be closers or markers-as-duplicate : this question is not answered in [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises), as all answers there treat of calls in isolation and do not explain how to deal with successive, dependent calls.

This question is basically the same as in [combining results from several async/await calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514800/combining-results-from-several-async-await-calls), but because of my slightly different context I fail to see how the solution therein can be adapted/mimicked.

I have two successive calls to a database, using an old API which only knows about callbacks. The second call needs objects/values returned by the first.

I have a working callback-version of the code,  as follows :

```
connection.query(sql1,function(error1,results1,fields1) {
    if(error1) {
         console.log("Error during first query",error1);
    }
    let sql2=computeUsingFirstResult(result1);

    connection.query(sql2,function(error2,results2,fields2) {
      if(error2) {
           console.log("Error during second query",error2);
       }
       doSomething(connection,results1,results2);
      })  
});
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt to do it in async/await-style :

```
const util = require('util');
async function firstQuery(connection) {
    return util.promisify(connection.query).call(sql1).catch(
        error1 => console.log("Error during first query : ", error1)
    );;
}

async function secondQuery(connection, result1) {
    let sql2 = computeUsingFirstResult(result1);
    return util.promisify(connection.query).call(sql2).catch(
        error2 => console.log("Error during second query : ", error2)
    );
}

let finalResult = {};

async function main() {
    const results1 = await firstQuery(connection);
    const results2 = await secondQuery(connection, results1);
    doSomething(connection, results1, results2);
    finalResult = [results1,results2];
    console.log("Here is the finalResult : ", finalResult);
}

main().catch(
    err => console.log("Something went wrong towards the end", err)
);
```

My async/await version fails as all the intermediate results are `undefined`. Yet, as far as I can see it should be equivalent to the non-async version above.

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: what's the error coming in?

Comment: @FahadSubzwari Everything is undefined. I forgot to mention that in my question, it's now added in, thx

Comment: did you try to `console` `results1` and `results2` ?  and if yes then what's the output

Comment: @EwanDelanoy please include your `util.promisify` code in your question

Comment: @Liam See https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original for the docs on `util.promisify` (which does what its name says, by the way)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches I am hoping you can try and see if either of them help:

(1) Bind the `util.promisify` to `connection` for both `firstQuery` and `secondQuery` something like so:

```js
async function firstQuery(connection) {
    return util.promisify(connection.query).bind(connection,sql1)().catch(
        error1 => console.log("Error during first query : ", error1)
    );;
}

// bind makes sure that internal bindings of connection object are in tact
```

If the above approach doesn't yield any result, try the next approach:

(2) Try using `Promises-Wrapper` instead of `util.promisify` for both firstQuery and secondQuery like so:

```js
function firstQuery(connection,sql1){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    connection.query(sql1,function(error1,results1,fields1){
      return error1 ? reject(error1):resolve(results1);
    })
  });
}
```

And now call them as you were in your code using Async/Await in the `main` function.

#### Few Potential bugs/typos I noticed in the code:

(1) firstQuery doesn't seem to be passed `sql1` as one of its arguments, maybe this is intentional if `sql1` exists in global scope.

(2) If you attach a catch block to both your queries, they will have an impact on your 2 calls (see comments in the code below):

```js
async function main() {
    const results1 = await firstQuery(connection); //<-- if this call fails, results1 will be undefined and the call will go to next step
    const results2 = await secondQuery(connection, results1); // same thing here
    doSomething(connection, results1, results2);
    finalResult = [results1,results2];
    console.log("Here is the finalResult : ", finalResult);
}
```

A possible solution is to remove the catch blocks from individual functions and just return the respective promises.

Then you can deal with them via a single try/catch block like this:

```js
async function main() {
    try{
      const results1 = await firstQuery(connection);
      const results2 = await secondQuery(connection, results1);
      doSomething(connection, results1, results2);
      finalResult = [results1,results2];
      console.log("Here is the finalResult : ", finalResult);
   }catch(err){
      console.log("Error",err);
   }
}
```

This will ensure that as soon as the first call fails, function goes straight to catch block without executing any other lines.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed help, I'll look into it